# Can't initialize Redis store [SOLVED]

Tags: node.js, express, session, redis

I'm trying to implement session authentication with Redis by following [this](https://blog.openreplay.com/sessions-management-and-authentication-with-node/) tutorial.

```
const session = require("express-session");
const redis = require('connect-redis');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const redisClient = require('redis').createClient({
    legacyMode:true
});

redisClient.connect().catch(console.log);

const RedisStore = redis(session);
```

After this when I try to start the server, I get this error:

> const RedisStore = redis(session);
> TypeError: redis is not a function

EDIT: The issue was with connect-redis version 7.1.0, after installing version 6.1.3 everythings works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of [connect-redis](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis) do not require you to use Node Redis in legacyMode.

Try replacing this:

```js
const redisClient = require('redis').createClient({
  legacyMode: true
});
```

With this:

```js
const redisClient = require('redis').createClient();
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but unfortunatelly it doesn't fix the issue. The issue is with the declaration of Redis store.

Comment: It it's any help and if you are using a version of Redis that supports JSON, I wrote [connect-redis-stack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis-stack) which stores the session in JSON instead of a string. I know it works. ;)

Comment: I don't doubt that, but I would prefer to resolve the issue rather than doing it differently.